# Unit tests with strings (Bloc Ios Development)

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, unit-testing

I'm currently going through bloc bootcamp and I need a little help with this code. I need to get these unit tests to pass. Below are two implementation files: The changes to the methods are to be done in the StringCheese.m while StringCheeseTests.m displays the failures. I've copied over only one failure so I can work through the rest. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

## StringCheeseTests.m

```
- (void)testThatCheeseFavoritingWorks {
    NSString *ricottaString = @"ricotta";
    NSString *favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:ricottaString];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is ricotta.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");

    NSString *goatString = @"goat";
    favoriteCheese = [self.stringCheese favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:goatString];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(favoriteCheese, @"My favorite cheese is goat.", @"Incorrect favorite cheese string returned.");
}
```

## StringCheese.m

```
- (NSString *) favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:(NSString *)cheeseName     {
    **//work here**
        return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood correctly: you're looking to write in the implmentation of `favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:` such that it passes its associated test.

What you need to do here is analogous to solving a maze by starting at the finish and working your way to the start (at least that's always how I did it as a kid).

Additionally, you need to understand the parameters being passed to [`XCTAssertEqualObjects`](http://appleprogramming.com/blog/2013/12/26/xctest-assertions-documentation/):

> // Generates a failure when [a1 isEqual:a2] is false (or one is nil and the other is not)
>   XCTAssertEqualObjects(a1, a2, format...)

From this you derive that `a2` in this case is `My favorite cheese is ricotta` and so you need to ensure that `a1` will give you that string ... also meaning that `favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:` needs to provide you that.

The method signature for `favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese:` takes in a string value and returns another string. From the test, we know that:

1. Passing `ricotta` as a parameter should return

   - `My favorite cheese is ricotta`
2. Passing `goat` as a parameter should return

   - `My favorite cheese is goat`

The constant value in this case is the string `My favorite cheese` with the variable being the parameter `cheeseName`. So in order for your tests to pass, you need to ensure that the `NSString` you pass in gets appended to your constant `NSString` and then that value gets returned. (Mind you, case and whitespace will matter).

I hope this answers your question without giving too much away. :)

Edit: Expanded answer

Your method in `StringCheese.m` will look something like this:

```
(NSString *)favoriteCheeseStringWithCheese: (NSString *)cheeseName{
    NSString *cheeseIntro = @"My favorite cheese is ";
    NSString *favoriteCheeseIntro = [cheeseIntro stringByAppendingString: cheeseName];

    return favoriteCheeseIntro;
}
```

So, when you're calling the method:

```
// declaring a variable
@property (nonatomic, strong) StringCheese *cheese;

// further down in the code
self.cheese = [[StringCheese alloc] init];
NSString *myFavoriteCheese = [self.cheese favoriteCheeseWithCheese:@"ricota"];

// myFavoriteCheese is now "My favorite cheese is ricotta"
```

Comment: Hey Louis, I appreciate all the advice! My main problem is starting this off. Maybe the problem lies with my the syntax or logic...or both. Any other hints you could give me regarding the StringCheese.m file? I'm brand new to development and objective-c and the instructions for these assignments are very vague.

Comment: it's hard to not reveal the full answer on this one since it's short, but use the results to guide the rest of your code

Comment: Louis, this helps tremendously. Now I can actually compare something to the lessons. Thanks man!

Comment: Glad I could help. When you have a moment, could you upvote and accept this as the answer if it solves your question?

Comment: Hey louis I accepted this as the answer, but I get an error saying I require 15 reputation. I'm new to all of this, so if there's something else I need to do just let me know and I'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: Ah yea forgot about that. No worries, thank you for accepting the answer